# facebook php sdk example got a fatal error

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I use the official example but didn't get it to work. It returned this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application. thrown in mylinl/etc../base_facebook.php on line 1336
```

Comment: Did you configure your app with an IP whitelist?

Comment: @Igy what is that? no..

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the App Settings—Advanced and put your IP to "Server IP Whitelist" field.